Hide duplicates in a query
I have a table (tblAdressen) and a table (tblKundeninteresse.Warengruppe) and a table (tblKundeninteresse.Artikel). Now lets say, a customer has an interest in 3 articles that are in the same group.
If I know make a query and filter it by interest group, the customer appears 3 times. By sorting by AddressID, I can at least see that the customer is shown 3 times but how can I change the SQL so that it only shows the customer 1 time?
I am a complete newby so I don't know if the information (I'll add the SQL code) is enough or if you need more information to help.
SELECT  tblAdressen.Anrede, 
        tblAdressen.Nachname, 
        tblAdressen.Vorname, 
        tblAdressen.Adresse, 
        tblAdressen.PLZ, 
        tblAdressen.Ort, 
        tblAdressen.Tel, 
        tblAdressen.Fax, 
        tblAdressen.Mailadresse, 
        tblKundeninteresse.Warengruppe, 
        tblKundeninteresse.Artikel, 
        tblArtikel.Bemerkung, 
        tblAdressen.Mailsenden, 
        tblAdressen.ID 
FROM    tblArtikel INNER JOIN (tblAdressen INNER JOIN tblKundeninteresse ON tblAdressen.ID = tblKundeninteresse.Kunde) ON tblArtikel.ID = tblKundeninteresse.Artikel 
WHERE   (((tblKundeninteresse.Warengruppe) Like [Formulare]![frmAbfrageWarengruppen]![cboWarengruppeAbfrage]) AND 
        ((tblAdressen.Aktiv)=True) AND ((tblKundeninteresse.aktiv)=True)) 
ORDER BY tblAdressen.ID;

I saw that you can group but I am not able to make it work

Add a GROUP BY clause just before the ORDER BY clause. Include all fields from tblAdressen. Use a grouping function like MIN or MAX on Warengruppe and Artikel to select the values you want from the tblKundeninteresse table to appear within the 1 tblAdressen row.
SELECT  tblAdressen.Anrede, 
        tblAdressen.Nachname, 
        tblAdressen.Vorname, 
        tblAdressen.Adresse, 
        tblAdressen.PLZ, 
        tblAdressen.Ort, 
        tblAdressen.Tel, 
        tblAdressen.Fax, 
        tblAdressen.Mailadresse, 
        
        MIN(tblKundeninteresse.Warengruppe) as Warengruppe, 
        MIN(tblKundeninteresse.Artikel) as Artikel, 

        tblArtikel.Bemerkung, 
        tblAdressen.Mailsenden, 
        tblAdressen.ID 
FROM    tblArtikel INNER JOIN (tblAdressen INNER JOIN tblKundeninteresse ON tblAdressen.ID = tblKundeninteresse.Kunde) ON tblArtikel.ID = tblKundeninteresse.Artikel 
WHERE   (((tblKundeninteresse.Warengruppe) Like [Formulare]![frmAbfrageWarengruppen]![cboWarengruppeAbfrage]) AND 
        ((tblAdressen.Aktiv)=True) AND ((tblKundeninteresse.aktiv)=True)) 

GROUP BY tblAdressen.Anrede, 
        tblAdressen.Nachname, 
        tblAdressen.Vorname, 
        tblAdressen.Adresse, 
        tblAdressen.PLZ, 
        tblAdressen.Ort, 
        tblAdressen.Tel, 
        tblAdressen.Fax, 
        tblAdressen.Mailadresse, 
        tblAdressen.Mailsenden, 
        tblAdressen.ID

ORDER BY tblAdressen.ID;


The code worked just fine but unfortunately, I can't edit the data in the query now. It says data records cannot not be updated.
Any idea why?
I would have to be able to check a the checkbox "Mailsenden" because after that I send an e-mail to all the clients that have the checkbox checked.
I read that you can make a temporary table. Would that work in this case and if so, can you tell me how that works?

I solved the problem by copying the data from the query to a new table. And then use this table to work since the change that will done won't have to be  appear in the original table.
Code:
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO [MailversandWarengruppe] FROM [abfKundeninteresseWarengruppe];"
